# RVM can not change gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Before I installed MySQL and restart my computer, my RVM works well.

If I type

```
rvm gemset use rails
```

It will show:

```
Using ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset rails
```

and then I type:

```
rvm gemset name
```

It shows:

```
rails
```

which is correct.

However, after I restart my computer, something strange happens.

Firstly, the system cannot find the command 'rvm', so I modified by ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/hanxu/.rvm/bin/:$PATH
```

Above is the content of my .bash_profile

Then rvm works.

Then I type:

```
rvm gemset use rails
```

It seems running well and shows:

```
Using ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset rails
```

However, when I examine it by asking rvm gemset name, it turns to be:

```
/Users/hanxu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

which is my default gemset, rather than "rails".

No matter how I set gemset, it always change to the default setting.

Can anyone tell me what's the problam?

Comment: Did you follow instructions during RVM installation? It requires a command added to your `.profile`/`.bashrc`/whatever.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, my RVM installation is automatically completed and I don't remember I have to set anything...

Comment: Sometimes it adds it for you. Just checking.

Comment: Do you have this string anywhere `[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`? This is what loads RVM in your session.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev.Problem solved! I add this code to my .bash_profile..thank you...BTW..can you explain what this code mean?

Comment: Posted as an answer, with a little explanation :)

Comment: Also, I'd remove that rvm entry from the PATH.

Comment: the PATH entry should be in `.bashrc` - so rvm is available also from non login shell, it's called binary or non interactive mode - when `rvm use` does not work, but also rvm does not do any interactions like displaying `rvm requirements` when first ruby is installed

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an .rvmrc file?

https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/

Comment: solved. add [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" to my bash_profile...

Answer (score 1):

Your RVM installation is most likely incomplete. Look for this string in your `.profile` / `.bashrc` / `.zshrc` or whatever else you might be using

```
[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

This command checks for existence of `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and, if found, loads it into the shell. This effectively loads the RVM. So, if you don't find this command, add it and open a new terminal window, RVM should be there.

Comment: files you mention should not include that line, it can break a lot of things like X serer or ssh, this line should be in `~/.bash_profile` or/and `~/.zprofile` alternatively   `~/.bash_login` or/and `~/.zlogin` - but the *login files are less preferred.

Comment: I am pretty sure that RVM was always putting it into `.profile`.  :)

Comment: for long time rvm was giving you information where to put it, then we have started adding sourcing to different *rc/*profile files, right now we got to the final version which is ~/.bash_profile ... and rest like stated above

Answer (score 1):

rvm has a command to fix sourcing:

```
rvm get stable --auto
```

the auto switch will update your *rc files, then it should be enough to open new terminal and it should be all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to switch gemset.

```
rvm use <ruby version>@<gemset name> --create
```

This command will switch rvm to given gemset and create it, if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add the user to the `rvm` group before I could use rvm.